# How to iterate through channels in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot with discord.py rewrite and I want to send a message in a particular channel which is NOT where the command will be used. If the command is used at X, message should be sent at Y channel. One option in my mind was to iterate through the channels of the server but I am unable to do it. Please help anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`discord.utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get):

```py
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    #Get your channel by name:
    channel = get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name="Channel Name")

    #Get your channel by ID:
    channel = get(ctx.guild.text_channels, id=channel_id)

    await channel.send("Some message")
```

Answer (score 0):

> One option in my mind was to iterate through the channels of the server but I am unable to do it.

What fails to work? Because [`guild.text_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.Guild.text_channels) is a *list* of all the server's text channels, and you should be able to iterate on that normally.